# Multiple Facebook Like Button Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, sdk, facebook-like

I have a gallery of images, each with it's own permalink page. There is a FB Like button for each image, on the gallery page and the permalink. The Like button is assigned to "like" the permalink URL, so each one is unique. Most of them work properly, but some seem to be connected (you like one and it automatically makes you like multiple) as if they share the same URL...but that's not possible because each is unique.

Using the FB linter, it's showing all data is proper so I can't see what's causing the overlap.

Check it out here http://watchsuburbia.com

Comment: if you refresh the page is the like you didn't click still marked as liked?

Comment: yes, and when you unlike one of them, it unlikes them all as well. The issue has seemed to been resolved when I switched from the HTML5 version to XFBML, unless it was coincidence it started working at the same time I made the switch.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be resolved. I switched from the HTML5 version to the XFBML implementation and that seemed to have cured the issue. If anyone could shed light on why it was happening with the HTML5, or if that could have even been the solution, that would be great.